# mechanism design for matrix of adjustable direction pointer

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, applied-mechanics, mechanisms

I need to construct a matrix of light pointers, each one aims in specific direction, and each pointer direction will be adjusted thousands times, size is flexible could be millimeters or centimeter but the cost of material and construction effort as low as possible.

what could be the best design and material choice?

Comment: Are you paid for this?

Comment: @SolarMike it's a research project, yes has small pudget

Comment: you can't do whatever you're doing by scanning a single high-peak-power beam and electronically flashing it in sync with the scan, like those party lights they have everywhere?

Comment: @PeteW didn't understand the suggestion.

Comment: I guess Peter W meant using one or more rotational light deflectors, usually seen in the parties, clubs, and on stages.

Comment: [these things](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=party+green+laser+light+pattern&iax=images&ia=images)

Comment: @PeteW +1 ... most of those projectors use a holographic slide to produce the patterns

Comment: Thank you all for the input, party lights are not suitable, 1st the required matrix is much larger, 2nd  the required light pointers must be adjustable separately